# Image trace becomes one box

Tags: adobe-illustrator, image-trace

I have an issue with image trace in Adobe Illustrator. Some PNG's become just a white box when I try to change it to vector using image trace. I tried opening the image and placing it to the artboard as well. still no luck. can anyone help me with this please?
TIA

Glorious

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This is difficult to answer without seeing anything. It would help if you were to post a screen shot showing the problem, or an example of the PNG you are trying to trace. Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/140054/edit) and add one. Thanks.

Comment: Trace results depend *entirely* upon *what* is being traced and the trace *settings*. Without some insight into those.... there's no way to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried varying the settings of the Tracing? It might be that your default setting is a stark black and white (and no greys) effect, and all colours in your .png are light enough to be converted to white. Find the Image Trace palette in the Window menu, and play around with the settings after your first trace attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing, but what you see as a 'box' could potentillay be an unexpanded shape. Try to select the 'box' and go to `Object → Expand` and click OK.

Then, go to outline mode by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, remove the enclosing rectangular shape and you should, hopefully, be left with a clean, traced shape.